# How do I create Multiple Meteor Projects?

Tags: meteor

How do I create more meteor projects? I tried "meteor create ..." but it said I can't create one inside another project.

Also, how do I delete a project?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I realized that I can just delete the project folder, navigate to another folder, and create a new project wherever I want a run the meteor command to start my server there. Thanks for reading.